# R: Doge boxplot when using factor() on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to dodge a simple boxplot so I can see two different measures at once, which should be rather simple but I have been super stuck.

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb4Rs.png)

For each intensity of "strength" I want to plot two different boxes next to each other, one for the True Postives and one for the False Positives.

[This is the mess I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c75H.png)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(strength))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = TP, fill = "TP"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = FP, fill = "FP"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TP" = "blue", "FP" = "red")) +
  labs(title = "Count",
       x = "Strength", y = "Count")
```

I am probably overlooking something, but why is position_dodge() not doing its job?

And here is a small example of what my data looks like:

```
# trial   strength     FP  TP
# 1       -3           5   6
# 1       2            6   7
# 1       1            2   1
# 2       -2           3   4
# 2       2            4   4
# 2       3            2   2
```

Comment: Seems FP and TP should be one column and then you can fill by the name of that column, after reshaping

Comment: Mh, I can see that this makes sense for categorical variables like gender or species. I understand I would basically have twice as many rows, and then either pick the FP or TP using "fill = dummy". Is there any way I can avoid reshaping? It feels very counter-intuitive.

Comment: Well, that's ggplot logic, the code will be shorter than yours, anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in the comments to make `position_dodge` work you have to reshape your data to long or tidy format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

Using some fake random example data:;

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  strength = rep(c(-3:-1, 1:3), each = 10),
  FP = sample(1:10, 60, replace = TRUE),
  TP = sample(1:10, 60, replace = TRUE)
)

data |>
  pivot_longer(c(FP, TP), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") |>
  ggplot(aes(factor(strength), value, fill = name)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TP" = "blue", "FP" = "red")) +
  labs(
    title = "Count",
    x = "Strength", y = "Count"
  )
```

[image: plot]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I already had my data in long format and somehow it didn't make sense to me to pivot_longer again for a plot. Now it does :)